# powershell c# convert comobject to .net

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using the following code to retrieve a specific address book from outlook:

```
$outlook = $(New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application)
$Session = $outlook.Session
$Session.Logon()
$ab = $Session.AddressLists | ? {$_.Name -eq 'test'}
```

then attempting to use C# to convert the `$ab` object to .net using the following:

```
$source = @"
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
public unsafe static class OAB
{
    public static void List(object Stream) 
    {
       var i = Stream as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressList; 
       return i;
    }
}
"@
$cp = new-object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters                                                                                                                                                                                                 
$cp.CompilerOptions = "/unsafe"
$cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add('C:\wkdir\refassem\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll')
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -CompilerParameters $cp
```

The error I receive is:

```
Since 'OAB.List(object)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
```

Disclaimer, I'm a complete newbie to C# so go easy on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your List function declared as a return type of `void` but you are returning a value. To fix, just change your function to this:

```
public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressList List(object Stream)
```

`void` functions mean that no value is going to be returns. If you do plan on returning a value, then you need to remove void and replace it with the type you want to return.